# Parsing XML with XPath in Python 3

Tags: python, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<document>
  <internal-code code="201">
    <internal-desc>Biscuits Wrapped</internal-desc>
    <top-grouping>Finished</top-grouping>
    <web-category>Biscuits</web-category>
    <web-sub-category>Biscuits (Wrapped)</web-sub-category>
  </internal-code>
  <internal-code code="202">
    <internal-desc>Biscuits Sweet</internal-desc>
    <top-grouping>Finished</top-grouping>
    <web-category>Biscuits</web-category>
    <web-sub-category>Biscuits (Sweets)</web-sub-category>
  </internal-code>
  <internal-code code="221">
    <internal-desc>Biscuits Savoury</internal-desc>
    <top-grouping>Finished</top-grouping>
    <web-category>Biscuits</web-category>
    <web-sub-category>Biscuits For Cheese</web-sub-category>
  </internal-code>
  ....
</document>
```

I have loaded it into a tree using this code:

```
try:
  groups = etree.parse(PRODUCT_GROUPS_XML_FILEPATH)
  root = groups.getroot()
  internalGroup = root.findall("./internal-code")
  LOG.append("[INFO] product groupings file loaded and parsed ok")
except Exception as e:
  LOG.append("[ERROR] PRODUCT GROUPINGS XML FILE ACCESS PROBLEM")
  LOG.append("[***TERMINATED***]")
  writelog()
  exit()
```

I would like to use XPath to find the correct  and then be able to access the child nodes of that group. So if I am searching for internal-code 221 and want web-category I would do something like:

```
internalGroup.find("internal-code", 221).get("web-category").text
```

I am not experienced with XML and Python and I have been staring at this for ages. All help very gratefully received. Thanks

Comment: http://lxml.de/extensions.html

Answer (score 2):

According to [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) documentation:

> ### XPath support
>
> This module provides **limited support for XPath expressions** for
>   locating elements in a tree. The goal is to support a small subset of
>   the abbreviated syntax; a full XPath engine is outside the scope of
>   the module.

Use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/):

```
>>> import lxml.etree as ET
>>>
>>> s = '''
... <document>
...   <internal-code code="201">
...     <internal-desc>Biscuits Wrapped</internal-desc>
...     <top-grouping>Finished</top-grouping>
...     <web-category>Biscuits</web-category>
...     <web-sub-category>Biscuits (Wrapped)</web-sub-category>
...   </internal-code>
...   <internal-code code="202">
...     <internal-desc>Biscuits Sweet</internal-desc>
...     <top-grouping>Finished</top-grouping>
...     <web-category>Biscuits</web-category>
...     <web-sub-category>Biscuits (Sweets)</web-sub-category>
...   </internal-code>
...   <internal-code code="221">
...     <internal-desc>Biscuits Savoury</internal-desc>
...     <top-grouping>Finished</top-grouping>
...     <web-category>Biscuits</web-category>
...     <web-sub-category>Biscuits For Cheese</web-sub-category>
...   </internal-code>
... </document>
... '''
>>>
>>> root = ET.fromstring(s)
>>> for text in root.xpath('.//internal-code[@code="221"]/web-category/text()'):
...     print(text)
...
Biscuits
```

Answer (score 2):

While I'm a big fan of lxml (see falsetru's answer), which you would need for full xpath support, the standard library's elementtree implementation does support enough to get what you need:

```
root.findtext('.//internal-code[@code="221]/web-category')
```

This returns the `text` property of the first matching element, which is enough if you are sure that code 221 will only occur once. If there could be more and you need a list:

```
[i.text for i in root.findall('.//internal-code[@code="221"]/web-category')]
```

(note that these examples would also work in lxml)